# How to run a command or batch file on another computer without using remote connection?

Tags: batch-file, remote-access, remote-desktop, screen-resolution

I have a test that aimed to change my screen resolution, when the problem is that the test runs on setup X and my laptop is setup Y.

When using remote connection, my test fails as it is recognizing the "remote" and resolution changes must be done on the setup itself

Is there a way to run it on the computer without remote connection?
Thanks!

Comment: So your question is how to remotely connect without remotely connecting?

Comment: no, I was wondering if I can create some pipe, or trigger somehow the .exe file

Comment: Run it as a scheduled task on the local machine.  That way it will be triggered by a local account and not an RDP session account

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create "c:\windows\notepad.exe"
```

[Note remote programs run invisible]

another way as a comment noted is Scheduled Tasks.

```
SCHTASKS /Create /S ABC /U user /P password /RU runasuser /RP runaspassword /SC WEEKLY /TN report /TR notepad.exe
```

then

```
 schtasks /run /tn report
```